# Entity Framework Core navigation property on ApplicationUser is sometimes null

Tags: entity-framework-core

I extended `IdentityUser` because users belong to organisations.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganisationId")]
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

In a razor page this works:

```
Organisation = (await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User)).Organisation;
```

However, in `Startup.cs` this doesn't work:

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
ApplicationUser rwb = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("rwb@...");
Organisation o = rwb.Organisation; // null :(
```

What's going on?

Why isn't Entity Framework Core loading the navigation properties? How do I get it to load navigation properties?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies`
2. In `Startup.cs` do `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()` like this:

```
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

3. Update all model classes to make all navigation properties `virtual`.